# asp.net not deserializing soap response

Tags: asp.net, wsdl, serialization

I have been given a wsdl and have used wsdl.exe to create my proxy classes.

I am able to call the function to initiate the request with some valid parameters and this returns my response object which is always EMPTY.

When i inspect the soap message response using fiddler the soap does have valid data that should be deserialzed to the proxy classes.

Can i manually intercept the derserializing call of the proxy classes generated by wsdl and check that .net is correctly derializing the soap response?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The empty object is most likely the result of a mismatch between the soap message and your proxy class. This can for example be caused by a difference in namespaces (newer version).